# Delphi 2007 R2 Code Completion not listing base class members

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I've recently installed Delphi 2007 R2 along with GExperts1.34, DelphiSpeedUp3.1 and IDEFixPack4.1.
The code completion feature doesn't work for me. Say, I create a new form and in the public section I hit CTRL+SPACE, I see only certain members of TObject (AfterConstruction, BeforeConstruction, Destroy etc) and Component Message handlers (i.e CM_XXX message handlers) in TCustomForm classes.
It doesn't list the Constructor of TObject and TForm.
Note I've disabled Refatoring package.

I tried removing all 3 experts and loading the .NET packages, but in vain. With default installation itself code completion doesn't work. It does however list all members when invoked inside a function/procedure.

I've also tried fresh installation on Windows 7 64-bit m/c. Code completion doesn't work.

Anyone faced this issue ?

Praveen.

Comment: When inheriting from `TObject` I would guess it is bacause `Create` is not `virtual`. But that does not explain the same thing for `TForm`. I have the same results when using code completion.

Answer (score 2):

Often in D2007 I have to build before code complete will pop up. I'd try that. I'm running D2007 on a 64bit Win 7 with all three of those plugins and have this issue frequently. Often a Clean/Build or opening a new Unit will fix it.

Comment: My experience with D2007 is that a rebuild (or just a syntax check) is usually sufficient to get code completion working again, but sometimes it just doesn't work at all, and I can never get it to code-complete on a variable that is declared as an array.